# Checking Contains value number in each of slice Go

Tags: arrays, list, go, slice

Is there an easy way to checking contains *number* value in each of slice using GO Lang, such that without for-range or for *slice*?

Comment: [slices.Contains](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Contains) might be what you are looking for (internally it still uses `range`). If not please clarify your question (adding your current solution, using `range` would be helpful).

Comment: thx sir, i just wanna learn another logic for that if there is another logic.

Comment: It really depends upon the specifics. If the slice is ordered then a [binary search](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Find) is an option. If you will be doing a lot of lookups then putting the data into a map can be quicker. I'm voting to close this because it's not really clear what you question is.

Comment: For a lot of lookups, turned out with a Map. Okay, i will try

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions:

## Using `slices.Contains`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
)

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Println(slices.Contains(arr, 3))
    fmt.Println(slices.Contains(arr, 6))
}
```

[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/aqrl9IVeVdV)

You can find the implementation of `slices.Contains` [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/exp/+/master:slices/slices.go#:%7E:text=//%20Contains%20reports%20whether,%7D)

## Using a set instead of a slice

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := map[int]struct{}{
        1: {},
        2: {},
        3: {},
        4: {},
        5: {},
    }
    _, contains3 := arr[3]
    fmt.Println(contains3)
    _, contains6 := arr[6]
    fmt.Println(contains6)
}
```

[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gwjdfmP4smK)

Read more about maps in go [here](https://gobyexample.com/maps) and how to create a set using maps [here](https://www.davidkaya.com/sets-in-golang/)

### Hope this helps :)

Comment: yeah, thx. turned out with a Map is other way